# Paleo-sea level of the Ionian basin

Tags: sea-level, paleogeography, isostasy

Q1 - I'm looking for research on paleo-sea level on the Ionian basin. I'm looking for sources that take into account tectonics.

Time period: Holocene - 30ka (and if possible, as far as 100ka).

I've found:

1. Vott (2007) (DOI: 10.1016/j.quascirev.2007.01.004)
2. Ferentinos (2012) (DOI: 10.1016/j.jas.2012.01.032)

Vott deals with the Pelopennese & Akarnania. I'm specifically looking for research on the Ionian islands. He does include include tectonics and shows that RSL varies regionally due to tectonics.

Ferentinos deals with the Ionian islands, but does not take tectonics into account.

Q2 - I've also been looking for a sea level curve but the closest I've gotten is the Adriatic sea.

Time period: same